# Is there any way to get wifi signal strength in ios through swift?

Tags: ios, swift, unity-game-engine, nehotspothelper

So our company is making an IOS app in unity and we need to fetch the WiFi signal strength for a functionality, which is checking in which places in the room is the WiFi signal strong or weak. Our minimum IOS version is 14.0.

From what I have read, it is impossible to fetch it through c#. That leaves option of using swift and bridging with c#. So in swift I know there's NEHotspotHelper, however that has its own set of conditions to trigger. So at this point i got 2 questions; is there any private API i can use in swift to fetch wifi signal strength, just for dev purposes not releasing on app store, and second is, considering we got all entitlements and all, how exactly would one even fetch wifi signal through NEHotspotHelper? or is there any better way to get the wifi signal strength?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72107644/calculating-wi-fi-strength-problematically